# Нужно сделать так, чтобы пока ошибка выдается, делать input

Tags: python, исключения

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('Тут мой API с сайта openweathermap')

try:
    place = input('What city do you want to know the weather in? ')
    observation = owm.weather_manager().weather_at_place(place)
    w = observation.weather
except:
    place = input(('No such city. Try again: '))
```

Нужно, чтобы пока выдается ошибка, спрашивать значение переменной place. И когда ошибка перестанет выдаваться, сделать остальные действия.

Изменено: код должен быть БЕЗ continue и break. Можно сделать с ними:

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('api-key')
while True:
    try:
        place = input('What city do you want to know the weather in? ')
        observation = owm.weather_manager().weather_at_place(place)
        w = observation.weather
        print(w.status)
        break
    except:
        continue
```

но это плохой пример написания кода.

Изменено 2: кажется решил! проверьте, нормальный код или нет.

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('api-key')

flag = True

while flag == True:
    try:
        place = input('What city do you want to know the weather in? ')
        observation = owm.weather_manager().weather_at_place(place)
        w = observation.weather
        print(w.status)
        flag = False
    except:
        flag = True
```

Comment: Поместить в цикл эту конструкцию?

Comment: ты не знаешь, что такое while?

Comment: Я знаю, что такое while, но не понимаю, как его тут можно использовать.

Comment: помещаешь всё в цикл, и если всё правильно, то выходишь из него

Comment: Тогда придется использовать break или continue, а это считается плохим примером написания кода

Comment: @IvanShevtsov не обязательно их использовать, выставляйте флаг и проверяйте его значение в условии

Comment: @IvanShevtsov, мне вариант 1 больше всех понравился -- самый лаконичный, в варианте 2 используются ненужные тут флаги. Почему вы считаете что continue и break это пример плохого кода? Кст, вместо `continue` просто `pass`: `except: pass`, т.к. после try/except ничего нет, поэтому не нужно писать `continue`

Comment: кто сказал, что break и continue плохой пример написания кода?

Comment: @gil9red есть статьи на английском, где это объясняется. В рунете ничего такого нет. Поскольку я новичок, я особо ничего не понял, но запомнил, что код без break и continue лучше и чище.

Comment: данный код с брейк лучше

Comment: В данном случае что break, что flag = False - одно и то же. Т.е. формально вы break будто бы и не используете, а фактически вы его просто замаскировали, затруднив, к тому же, чтение кода.

Comment: http://kpolyakov.blogspot.com/2012/10/break-break.html   здесь про это рассказывается. Теперь я согласен, мой код с break лучше, так как без break я задаю нову. переменную и поэтому ухудшается читаемость и оптимальность кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('api-key')
while True:
    try:
        place = input('What city do you want to know the weather in? ')
        observation = owm.weather_manager().weather_at_place(place)
        w = observation.weather
        print(w.status)
        break
    except:
        pass
```

kpolyakov.blogspot.com/2012/10/break-break.html здесь про это рассказывается. Теперь я согласен, мой код с break лучше, так как без break я задаю новую переменную и поэтому ухудшается читаемость и оптимальность кода.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('api-key')
w = None
while not w:
    try:
        place = input('What city do you want to know the weather in? ')
        observation = owm.weather_manager().weather_at_place(place)
        w = observation.weather
        print(w.status)
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Необязательно использовать `break` и `continue`:

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('api-key')
answered = False

while not answered:
    try:
        place = input('What city do you want to know the weather in? ')
        observation = owm.weather_manager().weather_at_place(place)
        w = observation.weather
        print(w.status)
        answered = True
    except:
        pass
```